# How to prevent not responding of tkinter program when running a while loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a medicine reminder in tkinter.It works but as I click the button "Notify", my program freezes and says not responding but the program still works.

```
from tkinter import *
from plyer import notification
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter.messagebox as msg

root = Tk()
root.title("Medicine reminder")


def notify():
    msg.showinfo("Reminder Set",f"You will be notified at {timeSlider.get()}. Make sure that you don't close the program")
    while True:
        hour = datetime.now().hour
        if hour == timeSlider.get():
            notification.notify(
                title=f"Take your medicine {medicine.get()}",
                message=f"You have scheduled it for {timeSlider.get()}",
                # displaying time
                timeout=15)
            break


Label(text="Medicine Reminder", font="comicsans 20 bold").pack(anchor="w", padx=10, pady=10)
medicine = StringVar()
medicine_entry = Entry(font="comicsans 20", textvariable=medicine)
medicine_entry.insert(0, "Name of medicine")
medicine_entry.pack(anchor="w", padx=10, pady=5)
timeSlider = Scale(from_=0, to=24, orient=HORIZONTAL)
Label(text="Enter the time you want to get notified at:", font="comicsans 15").pack(anchor="w", padx=10)
timeSlider.pack(anchor="w", padx=10)
Button(text="Notify me", font="comicsans 15 bold", relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=6, command=notify).pack(anchor="w",
                                                                                                      pady=15, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the `while` loop is causing the problem, try using `after`

Comment: Can u tell how to use **after**...but it should work with while loop also..how can I make it work with **while** loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code was that, you used an infinity loop with `while` which runs on the same thread as `tkinter`, hence it cannot run the window as the window is busy doing the while loop, using `after` which `tkinter` has inbuilt is **one** of the ways to tackle this problem.

**Method 1 (using `after`):**

```
def notify():
    global hour
    msg.showinfo("Reminder Set",f"You will be notified at {timeSlider.get()}. Make sure that you don't close the program")
    hour = datetime.now().hour
    root.after(timeSlider.get()*3600000,alert) #converting hour to ms

def alert():    
    notification.notify(
        title=f"Take your medicine {medicine.get()}",
        message=f"You have scheduled it for {timeSlider.get()}",
        # displaying time
        timeout=15)
```

`after()` method takes two arguments mainly:

- `ms` - time to be run the function
- `func` - the function to run after the given ms is finished.

The remaining part of the code remains the same

**Method 2 (Threading):**

```
import threading
....
Button(text="Notify me", font="comicsans 15 bold", relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=6, command=threading.Thread(target=notify).start).pack(anchor="w",
```

Just make the change to the buttons `command` argument and the rest of the code, stays still. This will do the trick, but then with threading it might still look inefficient, so I recommend using method 1.

Hope you got your doubts cleared, if any more errors, do let me know.

Cheers

Comment: What is this after...can you explain and we cannot write this with the help of while loop

Comment: Well I did a Google search about root.after and I understood root.after. Thanks, that's how we learn new things.

Comment: But timeslider.get is already in integer form so there is no need to typecast it

Comment: @Vasu Threading is nothing much, just like a normal thread, imagine cars going through a thread and they got into accident, so the thread might break, just like that, your tkinter runs on one thread and your `while` loop runs with it causing the thread to freeze, but with `threading` you make a new thread for that function with `while` and hence the thread with `tkinter` is going smooth, while the thread with `while` loop is frozen, and it doesnt matter for the other thread.

Comment: I request you to please upvote the question as StackOverflow is not allowing me to ask more questions.